# Applet Issue when using java 10 and IE 11

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

Trying to compile and run an application using Java 10 in (windows 7 - 64-bit machine) which contains Applets. So we compiled code in Java 10 and deployed to wildFly. All other pages will load but the Applet portion is not working with IE 11.

- If we use IE 8 (64-bit version) with Java 10 64 bit run time applets will run without any issues. Uninstalled IE updates and it defaulted to IE 8. That's why I used IE8.
- If we use IE 11 (Downloaded and installed 64-bit version) and tried but it will give a black cross mark in the place where the applet is loaded (In this scenario I had only JRE 10 in my machine as my runtime env ).
- If we install java 32-bit version (Java 8) then IE will use this (This time I had JRE 10 and JRE8), but got an error stating runtime version is 52.0(that is Java 8) and jar version is 54.0(Java 10). That means it is recognizing versions properly.

I tried all the available solution mentioned in different threads like changing the 'Enable Enhanced Protect Mode', Adding to compatibility settings, editing registry etc but no success. As Java 10 is 64 bit only, we can use only 64-bit version. Also as IE can handle both 32 and 64-bit is there any other configs I need to change? Same settings work in IE 8, not in IE11.

Note: There is a parallel project going on to migrate this application to an applet free version. But that will be live next year and by that time we need to have this run in Java 10.

Any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with IE but there should be some console available which logs errors.

Comment: Applets are deprecated and no longer supported. I the Applet plugin is no longer support and most browsers actively block it

Comment: Have you enabled `Scripting of Java Applets` in the `Internet Options` of IE as described here: https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml

Comment: @BasilBourque yes it is enabled. If I use application compiled in Java 8  - 32 bit, it will run without any issues.